# What is this logical circuit and how does it work?

Tags: logic, circuit

[This is the logic circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yO2N.jpg)
I've drawn a truth table and I've found that when:

C and D are true, then Q is true and complement Q is false

C is true but D is false, then complement Q is true and Q is false

The rest I don't see how you could know. Any tips or pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a D-latch!

When C is true (1) the value of D goes to Q.
When C is false (0), anything happens. (The Q dont change)

This question isnt for here. Try [this](https://www.electronicspoint.com)